# Access a mounted partition in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to access a mounted drive, but got a permission issue:

```
sudo mkdir data
sudo chmod 755 data
sudo mount UUID=1512a97c-436d-4ad9-b1b5-0b157268d765 /data

cd /data
-bash: cd: /data: Permission denied
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission for `/data` you might need to change permission of `/data` or access it using sudo user. Further when you are creating data folder check you are in root directory or not

Comment: it is in root, before mounting, owner of /data is root, after mounting, it become 999:

Comment: 4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jun  9 11:51 data  after mounting : 

4.0K drwx------   7  999  999 4.0K Jun  3 06:16 data

Comment: after mounting you can change permission or access this diretory from root user